# Is parseInt() faster than toString()?

Tags: javascript, performance

I am checking to see if a number array is [pandigital](https://projecteuler.net/problem=32) in JavaScript. In short, this means that if it is a 9-digit number, then it must have the all the digits 1-9. I have the number array sorted already, and I have the following loop:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    if(parseInt(digits[i]) != i+1) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

But I was just wondering if the following would be faster:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    if(digits[i] != (i+1).toString()) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I'm not sure which one would be faster. I feel that converting to a string would be faster than parsing to a number. I've tried to run a few tests, but I haven't really come up with anything conclusive: my computer is old and results are all over the place.

Which one would be faster, and why? Would this difference in speed increase with larger numbers?

**EDIT**

`digits` is a array of sorted strings of digits, e.g.:

```
var digits = [ "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9" ];
```

Comment: It'd probably be even faster to take advantage of the fact that the `!=` operator will compare single-digit numbers and their string versions as equal or not equal exactly how you want!

Comment: That's almost certainly going to 1) depend heavily on the specifics of the engine implementation and 2) not matter until you're working with numbers you can't natively handle. Also, you're not considering the three other approaches I can think of and others I'm not thinking of.

Comment: @Pointy Look at the link to the project euler question I am trying to solve: yes, I am comparing only single digits.

Comment: That is, try just `if (digits[i] != i+1) {`

Comment: @Pointy Sorry, forgot to mention that `digits` is a string of digits as a string. I'll update the question

Comment: @JonathanLam right. In JavaScript, `"2" == 2` is `true` and `"2" != 3` is `true`.

Comment: @JonathanLam JS is loosely typed, `"2" == 2` will evaluate to `true`.

Comment: @brso05 See the link. It is for Project Euler

Comment: @Pointy I didn't know that! That would simplify things.

Comment: how about scrapping the whole for loop and doing `return digits.join("") === "123456789"`.

Comment: @andi I hadn't considered that either! What wonderful solutions!

Comment: @andi: This might not work with `n`-digit numbers. You'd need `digits.sort().join("") === "123456789".slice(0, digits.length)`

Comment: @Bergi true but the constraint of the project Euler question implies that the number will be exactly 9 digits long for the test to make any sense; presumably that would be filtered out before getting to this point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to jsperf.com, parseInt() is much faster (at least on my pc and chrome).

Test it for yourself:

[**TEST**](http://jsperf.com/parseinttostring)

[image]

Comment: Nice test. But do you know why that is so? (And toStirng is spelled wrong in the title)

Comment: @JonathanLam For this question, and I don't mean to sound obtuse, but why do you need to know exactly *why* `parseInt()` is faster? Also, the title is just a demo; did you really need to point out a simple typo over thanking @mmm for his help? :P

Comment: This test makes no sense. `digits` is clearly supposed to be a string, not an array of numbers. (admittedly [`parseInt` still appears to be faster](http://jsperf.com/parseinttostring/2))

Comment: Yes, OP updated the question with this information after the test was written @Bergi

Comment: The DV is very harsh, considering the updated question.

Comment: @mmm, BenM: You mean [revision 2](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/35563511/revisions)? I didn't even see that (and thought `digits` was a string, not an array of strings). Anyway, the test was wrong because `digits[i]` needs to be a string for the question to make sense at all.

Comment: I added [revision 4](http://jsperf.com/parseinttostring/4). Avoiding string conversion is much, much faster than the other options.

Comment: @mmm Thanks. This is the best answer to my original question

Answer (score 1):

I would assume neither is very fast, depending on how good the optimizer is.

It's likely much faster to avoid string conversions entirely and use the ordinal values directly (no temporary allocations this way):

```
for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    if (digits.charCodeAt(i) != 48 /* '0' */ + i + 1) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Here's my stab at detecting a pandigital number quickly:

```
function pandigital(s) {
    var seen = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0];
    for (var i = 0; i != s.length; ++i) {
        var ord = s.charCodeAt(i);
        if (ord <= 48 || ord > 48 + s.length) return false;
        if (seen[ord - 48 - 1]++) return false;
    }
    return s.length > 0;
}
```

Comment: I think that the OP is probably splitting the string on `""` and then sorting that array. Also note the clever comment from @andi in the question thread.

Comment: Yes. That would probably be more of a bottleneck, heh. Andi's code is by far the simplest and most elegant solution, but likely not the fastest (especially if the string isn't being split and sorted in the first place).